# The target "/t:native_metrics" does not exist in the project

Tags: javascript, node.js, newrelic

i want to install newrelic on my project but i'm receiving from de console:

```
node_modules\@newrelic\native-metrics\build\bind ing.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "/t:native_metrics" does not exist in the project.
```

in another machine works perfectly. i really would appreciate if some one could help with that, i already tried this from newrelic https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/newrelic-native-metrics-does-not-install-on-windows-10-from-corrupt-vcxproj/54625/3

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the version of node-gyp. A change was introduced into node-gyp 
version 3.7.0 that prepends `/t:` to the build target on Windows machines. The `./lib/pre-build.js` file that New Relic uses to bootstrap the build also prepends `/t:` to the target which results in a value of `/t:/t:native_metrics` being passed to MSBuild, which isn't valid. You can fix this by installing an older version of node-gyp. Depending on how npm is set up on your machine you may also have to set the `npm_config_node_gyp` environment variable to the path of the older version of node-gyp so it gets picked up by the New Relic bootstrapper.

Comment: Solution was delete folders npm, node-gyp and npm-cache and than install on Windows **option 2** https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp. Now it works!