# The target “/t:native_metrics” does not exist in the project

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-gyp

I am trying to run `npm install` but I am getting the following error:

`node_modules\@newrelic\native-metrics\build\binding.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "/t:native_metrics" does not exist in the project.`

I tried a few suggested solutions like: completely uninstalling nodejs (I also removed all the leftover folder in AppData), I tried downgrading `node-gyp` to an older version rather than the latest. I tried this solution here: [The target "/t:native_metrics" does not exist in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526377/the-target-tnative-metrics-does-not-exist-in-the-project)

I also uninstalled and installed Python2.7 but that didn't help. I removed and installed Windows Build Tools but nothing. I also removed all the npm, npm-cache and .node-gyp folder and that didn't do the trick. 
I am not getting the error when I run `npm install` on two other machines. 
Anyone have any suggestion before I do a clean install of my Windows?

Comment: Hi @novica, same happening to me. I wonder if you found a way to fix it and willing to share it :)